# Div not centering in bootstrap based template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Theme Link](http://oxygen.goldeyestheme.com/oxygen/)

If you go to the prices sections you'll see 4 pricing table, if i remove 1 pricing table it all becomes left aligned!!

How can i center them, i tried `margin:0 auto;` but it did'nt work, i'm new to bootstarp please help

The mail table class which warps up the 4 price boxes has following css

```
ul.tables {
    margin: 70px auto 0;
}
```

the HTML is

```
<ul class="tables">

                <!-- Table -->
                <li data-animation-delay="300" data-animation="fadeIn" class="col-xs-3 pricing-table relative animated fadeIn visible">
                    <!-- Table Inner -->
                    <div class="table-inner">
                        <!-- Table Top -->
                        <div class="price-table-top">
                            <!-- Header -->
                            <h3 class="uppercase bold white absolute">starter</h3> 
                            <!-- Image Link -->
                            <a class="price-table-img pattern-grid">
                                <!-- Your Image -->
                                <img alt="" src="images/tables/1.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Price Circle -->
                            <a class="price-circle absolute dark">
                                <!-- Price -->
                                <p class="price playball bigger">$19</p>
                                <!-- Timely -->
                                <p class="timely italic normal">Monthly</p>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- End Table Top -->
                        <!-- Price Plans -->
                        <ul class="price-plans">
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">5 bonus</span> points every month</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">2 Months</span> Support</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">10</span> Subdomains</li>
                        </ul><!-- End Price Plans -->
                        <!-- Buy Now Button -->
                        <a class="price-buy-now uppercase semibold white" href="#">Buy Now</a>
                    </div><!-- End Table Inner -->
                </li><!-- End Table -->


                <!-- Table -->
                <li data-animation-delay="300" data-animation="fadeIn" class="col-xs-3 pricing-table relative animated fadeIn visible">
                    <!-- Table Inner -->
                    <div class="table-inner">
                        <!-- Table Top -->
                        <div class="price-table-top">
                            <!-- Header -->
                            <h3 class="uppercase bold white absolute">standart</h3> 
                            <!-- Image Link -->
                            <a class="price-table-img pattern-grid">
                                <!-- Your Image -->
                                <img alt="" src="images/tables/2.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Price Circle -->
                            <a class="price-circle absolute dark">
                                <!-- Price -->
                                <p class="price playball bigger">$39</p>
                                <!-- Timely -->
                                <p class="timely italic normal">Monthly</p>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- End Table Top -->
                        <!-- Price Plans -->
                        <ul class="price-plans">
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">5 bonus</span> points every month</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">2 Months</span> Support</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">10</span> Subdomains</li>
                        </ul><!-- End Price Plans -->
                        <!-- Buy Now Button -->
                        <a class="price-buy-now uppercase semibold white" href="#">Buy Now</a>
                    </div><!-- End Table Inner -->
                </li><!-- End Table -->


                <!-- Table -->
                <li data-animation-delay="300" data-animation="fadeIn" class="col-xs-3 pricing-table relative active animated fadeIn visible">
                    <!-- Table Inner -->
                    <div class="table-inner">
                        <!-- Table Top -->
                        <div class="price-table-top">
                            <!-- Header -->
                            <h3 class="uppercase bold white absolute">professional</h3> 
                            <!-- Image Link -->
                            <a class="price-table-img pattern-grid">
                                <!-- Your Image -->
                                <img alt="" src="images/tables/3.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Price Circle -->
                            <a class="price-circle absolute dark">
                                <!-- Price -->
                                <p class="price playball bigger">$59</p>
                                <!-- Timely -->
                                <p class="timely italic normal">Monthly</p>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- End Table Top -->
                        <!-- Price Plans -->
                        <ul class="price-plans">
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">5 bonus</span> points every month</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">2 Months</span> Support</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">10</span> Subdomains</li>
                        </ul><!-- End Price Plans -->
                        <!-- Buy Now Button -->
                        <a class="price-buy-now uppercase semibold white" href="#">Buy Now</a>
                    </div><!-- End Table Inner -->
                </li><!-- End Table -->


                <!-- Table -->
                <li data-animation-delay="300" data-animation="fadeIn" class="col-xs-3 pricing-table relative animated fadeIn visible">
                    <!-- Table Inner -->
                    <div class="table-inner">
                        <!-- Table Top -->
                        <div class="price-table-top">
                            <!-- Header -->
                            <h3 class="uppercase bold white absolute">enterprise</h3> 
                            <!-- Image Link -->
                            <a class="price-table-img pattern-grid">
                                <!-- Your Image -->
                                <img alt="" src="images/tables/4.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Price Circle -->
                            <a class="price-circle absolute dark">
                                <!-- Price -->
                                <p class="price playball bigger">$79</p>
                                <!-- Timely -->
                                <p class="timely italic normal">Monthly</p>
                            </a>
                        </div><!-- End Table Top -->
                        <!-- Price Plans -->
                        <ul class="price-plans">
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">5 bonus</span> points every month</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">2 Months</span> Support</li>
                            <li class="price-plan uppercase bold italic"><span class="colored">10</span> Subdomains</li>
                        </ul><!-- End Price Plans -->
                        <!-- Buy Now Button -->
                        <a class="price-buy-now uppercase semibold white" href="#">Buy Now</a>
                    </div><!-- End Table Inner -->
                </li><!-- End Table -->

                <!-- Clear -->
                <li class="clear"></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto left/right margins only work (for centering content) for elements that have a width other than auto (which is the default for most elements).

```
ul.tables {
    width: 65%; /* make this whatever works */
    margin: 70px auto 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

It's worth noting that since you're using the Bootstrap `col-` classes for your `<li>` elements, you could get the centering CSS "for free" by simply applying the `row` class to your `ul.tables` element:

```
<ul class="row tables">

    <!-- ... -->

</ul>
```

Comment: further to this: the section `col-xs-3` in the `<li>`'s class attribute is attempting to make each of the columns `width:25%;`, if you are going to be using only 3 list items, you're best to set them to `col-xs-4` (which will set them to `width:33.333%;` of their container

Comment: @Neox That's not really a Bootstrap-specific problem, just basic CSS. If you're new to web development or just light on experience, head over to http://www.webplatform.org/ and read some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
ul.tables
{
width: 75%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and replace your li class `col-xs-3` with `col-xs-4`

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g9CXt/

If you want an actual understanding of how this works then let me take you step by step on where things went wrong, how you reasoned things, and how things actually work on the pricing table your tried to use.

To do this we need to emphasize the four main things that define the structure of this table that you took.

---

1. `<li class="col-xs-3 pricing-table relative animated fadeIn visible" data-animation="fadeIn" data-animation-delay="300">`
2. `<ul class="tables">`
3. `<div class="inner prices">`
4. `<section id="prices" class="container">`

The css in these four elements is what creates that entire section's structure.

---

Let's start with the be biggest elements and work our way down to the most specific elements.

## The `<`section`>`

#### The Boostrap Css

.container{ This css class gives the entire section 'container' a 100% width as long as the media screen is above 1200px. Less importantly, it sets the margins and padding to 0px.}

#### The Custom Css

None in the `<section>` element

#### Notes

This is what we call the container. It sets a width of 100% (any browser size). It wraps the content of this section.

## The `<`div`>`

#### The Boostrap CSS

None worth noting

#### The Custom CSS

```css
.inner{
    /* This css class is a custom class that is not included in bootstrap. This has four major style attributes that help define the entire structure. It established a **max-width:1170px**, it centers all of the elements' 1170pxs with **margin:0 auto**, it aligns the text of all children under this div with **text-align:center**, and lastly it applies a a **padding: 75px 0px 0px 0px** to the top of all of this content to provide white space from the previous `<section>` */
}
```

#### Notes

This is what sets the defined width as Tieson T. said. It allows you to use `margin:0 auto` BECAUSE it has a defined width.

## The `<`ul`>`

#### Notes

This is what rewraps the four individual columns. Think of it as the 'new container' now that the 'max-width' has been formed in our previous `<div>` element. It also establishes that the margins are automatically determined. Just so you know, automatic margins mean that the margins take up as much space that is not already taken by the width of the elements. That said, the margins were already automatically established through `<div>`, so the css in this element is rather redundant.

## The `<`li`>`

#### The Boostrap Css

```css
.col-xs-3{
    /* This css class establishes how the individual pricing columns will be formatted. Most importantly, this uses **width:25%** because there are 4 columns. It also uses **float:left** in order to assure all columns stay on one line. */
}
```

#### Notes

Defines the width of the individual pricing pages through the css class `.col-xs-3` (25% width, `float:left`). You would change this to `.col-xs-#` to make the width appropriate for you. That said, I am a big believer in using `display:inline-block` for this scenario and NOT `float:left`/`right`.

## Advice for studying this

Download Google Chrome, go to the web page http://oxygen.goldeyestheme.com/oxygen/press,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd> all at once after the page loads, press the magnifying glass, then hover your mouse icon over a price column until the entire thing turns blue, and you can explore from there.